# How do I import vertex and edge attributes for a bipartite network in igraph?

Tags: r, igraph

I want to analyze a dataset of companies that are related through shared corporate directors.  The problem is that I first create a bipartite network and then work with its projection, and I don't know when to attach the vertex attributes.

I'm starting with a large dataframe with the following columns:

CompanyID, Director ID, CompanyName, Revenue, Size, Ticker, DirectorName, Director Position, ChairmanDummy, NumberofBoardSeats

I turn the df into a graph:
net<-graph.data.frame (df, directed = FALSE)

This gives me a graph ("net") of: CompanyID, Director ID relationships

I can't add vertex attributes at this stage because it is a bipartite network, and I only have a table of attributes for the company vertexes (the columns CompanyID, Director ID, CompanyName, Revenue, Size, Ticker).  If I try to include  "vertices=nodes"  -- nodes being a file that contains the company vertexes, I get the error:
"Some vertex names in edge list are not listed in vertex data frame"
presumably because the table doesn't include data on the director vertexes.

So I move on to taking the bipartite projection that I am interested in:

V(net)$type <- V(net)$name %in% df$source
table(net$type)
is_bipartite(net)

net.list<-bipartite_projection(net, multiplicity = TRUE)
firms<-net.list[[1]]

Here, firms is a projection of firm-firm relationships where two firms share the same company director.

But, at this point, how do I add the data on the attributes associated with each vertex (each company) once I have already created a graph?

As above, I have the "nodes" file that contains the information associated with each company, but I don't know how to attach it to the firms graph.

I tried exporting the graph as a data.frame:  (Firms.df<- as_data_frame(firms)
But get the error "cannot coerce class ""igraph"" to a data.frame"

As a related question, I'm unsure of how to deal with the information on the director vertexes that are the part of the bipartite projection that I am essentially discarding.  Some of these are director attributes (name, number of director positions) but others are specific to a firm-director pair (position).  These are less useful for my analysis, but my sense is that I would need to subset the initial dataframe to select the features that I am interested in (eg only directors that belong to 10 or more boards) and then construct the network from the resulting subset of data - is this the best way to approach them?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please provide the details on what have you tried so far?
Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: from <- c('A','B','B','B','C','C','D')
to <- c('1','1','2','3','1','4','4' )
revenue <- c(10,20,20,20,30,30,40)
directorships <-c('2','2','4','6','2','8','8' )
df.tst <- as.data.frame(cbind (from, to, revenue, directorships))

net.tst<-graph.data.frame (df.tst, directed = FALSE)

V(net.tst)$type <- V(net.tst)$name %in% df.tst$from 
table(net.tst$type) 
is_bipartite(net.tst)

Bipar<-bipartite_projection(net.tst, multiplicity = TRUE)
Firms<-Bipar[[1]]
Firms

The issue seems to be that the bipartite projection step does not retain the vertex attributes.  Is there a work around?

Comment: In addition to learning igraph, I am clearly also learning how to format my comments.  Sorry about the lack of line breaks.

Comment: To export your graph as an edge or node frame try using [igraph::as_data_frame(firms, what=c("edges", "vertices", "both"))](http://igraph.org/r/doc/graph_from_data_frame.html). If you have other packages loaded, it might choose the wrong function. You also need to choose one of _edges, vertices and both_ to specify what your data frame should look like.